# Python: isDigit() with decimal numbers?

Tags: python, input, calculator

i'm coding a basic calculator in python that takes in input 2 numbers and the operation to do. In a part of the code, i do a check to verify if the input is a number with the isDigit() function. It works but not with decimals like "2.5" or "3.25". Here is the code if you need it : [My Code](http://pastebin.com/DaE67ubW)

Please let if know if i use isDigit() wrong, or if there is another function that does what i want.

Comment: See the comprehensive post I duped you to; use `float()` to try and convert such input and handle the exception that might raise.

Comment: Thank you, the solution in the link you gave works ! Sorry for the duplicate.